# Form editing in Django UpdateView

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to alter the form like its label and possibly more.
I'm using get_form method of UpdateView to alter the form but it's not working

views.py

```
class SystemUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
"""CRUD update view for :class:`~.System` objects"""

form_class = SystemForm
model = System
permission_required = 'services.change_system'
success_message = "System '%(name)s' updated successfully."
template_name = 'systems/system_form.html'

# when system edited need to modify accountable_team_history

def form_valid(self, form):

    system = self.get_object()

    if form.instance.accountable_team is not None:
        if system.accountable_team == form.instance.accountable_team:
            pass
        else:
            try:
                old_team_history = system.accountable_team_history.get(end_date__isnull=True)

                old_team_history.end_date = datetime.datetime.now()

                old_team_history.save()
            except AccountableTeamHistory.DoesNotExist:
                pass

            new_history = AccountableTeamHistory(resource=system,
                                         accountable_team=form.instance.accountable_team,
                                         effective_date=datetime.datetime.now())

            system.accountable_team_history.add(new_history)

            system.save()

def get_form(self, form_class=SystemForm):

    form_class.fields['primary_purpose_business_use'].label = "Primary purpose/business use"
    form_class.fields['secondary_purpose_business_uses'].label = "Secondary purpose/business uses"

    return form_class
```

SystemForm is imported from forms.py I dont think get_form method is doing anything for now. What could be possibly wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate an instance of form_class and return it. [See the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form)

```
def get_form(self, form_class=SystemForm):
    form = form_class()
    form.fields['primary_purpose_business_use'].label = "Primary purpose/business use"
    form.fields['secondary_purpose_business_uses'].label = "Secondary purpose/business uses"

    return form
```

Comment: Thank you but still no luck :(

Comment: This is weird because I'm doing the same get_form on my createview... updateview just doesn't work...

Comment: Try remove the declaration of form_class at class scope

Comment: Then, when i click the "update" which sends the POST, I get ImporperlyConfigured error. Does this suggest something?

Comment: A small note for anyone trying to remove a label using this method. You would need to set the label to an empty string, not `None`.